# Vue.js radio button no reactive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, radio-button, vue-reactivity

I am trying to pass the radio button value to its parent
here is the example:

Child

```
<template>
  <radio v-model="type" value="TypeOne" @change="TypeOne()"></el-radio>
  <radio v-model="type" value="TypeTwo" @change="TypeTwo()"></el-radio>
</template>

<script>     
 export default {
  methods: {
      TypeOne() {
        this.$emit('input', 'TypeOne');
      },
      TypeTwo() {
        this.$emit('input', 'TypeTwo');
      }
    }
 }
</script>
```

parent

```
<template>
 <component @input="onTypeChange"></component>
 <div v-show="type"></div>
 <div v-show="!type"></div>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
   data() {
     return {
       type: 'true',
     };
   },
   methods: {
    onTypeChange () {
      var TypeOne = false
      var TypeTwo = false
      if (TypeOne == TypeOne) {
        this.type = false;
      } else if (TypeTwo == TypeTwo) {
        this.type = true;
      } else {
          console.log('typeChanged');
          return false;
      }
    }
  }
 }
</script>
```

I am trying to use radio data to hide or show some element in the parent component. in initial selection it works but after radio selection is changed it does not update the parent. How can I make the radio data reactive in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You passed a parameter when you called `this.$emit('input', 'TypeOne');`
but the method emitted is not accepting a parameter.

Add a parameter on `onTypeChange()` and use the parameter on your logic

```
onTypeChange (type) {
  if (type == 'TypeOne') {
    this.type = false;
  } else if (type == 'TypeTwo') {
    this.type = true;
  } else {
    console.log('typeChanged');
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: This fixed my problem. Thank you.